# call function in jquery-ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a show function in my test.php page , how may i call show() function in ajax
 instead **url:test.php** in following code

```
$.ajax({
  url: **'test.php'**,
  success: function(result) {
    alert(ersult);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this as jQuery knows nothing about php functions. An AJAX call is always performed to some server side script in which processing takes place and returns the result. So you could call this function in the `test.php` script.